# Do "Subject Matter" and "Pedagogical Content Knowledge" mean the same things in ESL/EFL?

Tags: english, terminology

Do "[Subject Matter](https://sites.google.com/site/pethanmath/portfolio/subject-matter)" and "[Pedagogical Content Knowledge](https://download.atlantis-press.com/article/25882125.pdf)" mean the same things in ESL/EFL?